# solving sets of partial Differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Considering two functions  $\psi_{1}(u,v)$ and $\psi_{4}(u,v)$. we have these two parial differential equation for them

$(-2 i Sech[\frac{u}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{4}}{\partial u}+2 i Sech[\frac{v}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{4}}{\partial v})+(2 i Sech[\frac{u}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{1}}{\partial u}+2 i Sech[\frac{v}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{1}}{\partial v}-m\psi_{1})=0$

$(2 i Sech[\frac{u}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{1}}{\partial u}-2 i Sech[\frac{v}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{1}}{\partial v})+(-2 i Sech[\frac{u}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{4}}{\partial u}-2 i Sech[\frac{v}{\alpha}] \frac{\partial\psi_{4}}{\partial v}-m\psi_{4})=0$

I need to find $\psi_{1}(u,v)$ and $\psi_{4}(u,v)$
I wrote these code for them but I don't know why is the problem and why it doesn't give the answer.

```
DSolve[{((-2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ4[u, v], u]+2 ISech[v/α] D[ψ4[u, v], v]) + (-m ψ1 [u, v] + 2 I  Sech[u/α] D[ψ1[u, v], u] +2 I  Sech[v/α] D[ψ1[u, v], v])) ==0, ((2I Sech[u/α] D[ψ1[u, v], u]-2 I  Sech[v/α] D[ψ1[u, v], v]) + (-m ψ4[u, v] - 2 I  Sech[u/α] D[ψ4[u, v], u]-2 I  Sech[v/α] D[ψ4[u, v], v])) == 0}, {ψ1[u,v],ψ4[u, v]}, {u, v}]
```

I also tried `NDSolve` but still didn't get the answer

Comment: For a numerical solution, it is necessary to determine the initial and boundary conditions.

Comment: The code contains several errors. I corrected them in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This system of equations also can be solved symbolically, although not with `DSolve`.  Beginning with

```
eq = {((-2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ4[u, v], u] + 2 I Sech[v/α] D[ψ4[u, v], v]) + 
      (-m ψ1[u, v] + 2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ1[u, v], u] + 2 I Sech[v/α] D[ψ1[u, v], v])), 
      (( 2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ1[u, v], u] - 2 I Sech[v/α] D[ψ1[u, v], v]) + 
      (-m ψ4[u, v] - 2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ4[u, v], u] - 2 I Sech[v/α] D[ψ4[u, v], v]))};
```

make the transformation,

```
rulet = {Sinh[u/α] -> ut, Sinh[v/α] -> vt};
```

with corresponding transformation of derivatives,

```
ruled = {Derivative[1, 0][ψ_][u, v] -> Derivative[1, 0][ψ][ut, vt] Cosh[u/α]/α, 
         Derivative[0, 1][ψ_][u, v] -> Derivative[0, 1][ψ][ut, vt] Cosh[v/α]/α, 
         ψ_[u, v] -> ψ[ut, vt]}
```

Applying this transformation then eliminates the independent variables from the coefficients of the equations.

```
Simplify[α eq /. ruled]
(* {((-2 I D[ψ4[ut, vt], ut] + 2 I D[ψ4[ut, vt], vt]) + 
      (-m α ψ1[ut, vt] + 2 I D[ψ1[ut, vt], ut] + 2 I D[ψ1[ut, vt], vt])), 
      (( 2 I D[ψ1[ut, vt], ut] - 2 I D[ψ1[ut, vt], vt]) + 
      (-m ψ4[ut, vt] - 2 I D[ψ4[ut, vt], ut] - 2 I D[ψ4[ut, vt], vt]))} *)
```

It follows, therefore, that the solution can be decomposed into Fourier modes,

```
{ψ1 -> Function[{ut, vt}, ψ10 Exp[I ku ut + I kv vt]], 
 ψ4 -> Function[{ut, vt}, ψ40 Exp[I ku ut + I kv vt]]}
```

or, in terms of the original variables,

```
{ψ1 -> Function[{u, v}, ψ10 Exp[I ku Sinh[u/α] + I kv Sinh[v/α]]], 
 ψ4 -> Function[{u, v}, ψ40 Exp[I ku Sinh[u/α] + I kv Sinh[v/α]]]}
```

The wavenumbers, `{ku, kv}` can be determined in the usual manner,

```
Simplify[eq Exp[-I ku Sinh[u/α] - I kv Sinh[v/α]]/.%];
CoefficientArrays[% I α/4, {ψ10, ψ40}] // Last // Normal // Det
(* ku kv - (m^2 α^2)/16 *)
```

Comment: Dear @bbgodfrey many thanks for your answer. I'm very glad that it has exact solution

Comment: I have a more general solution and shall post it later this week.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a numerical solution

```
eq = {((-2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ4[u, v], u] + 2 I*Sech[v/α] D[ψ4[u, v], v]) 
        + (-m ψ1[u, v] + 2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ1[u, v], u] 
        + 2 I Sech[v/α] D[ψ1[u, v], v])) == 0, ((2 I*Sech[u/α] D[ψ1[u, v], u] - 
        2 I Sech[v/α] D[ψ1[u, v], v]) + (-m ψ4[u, v] - 2 I Sech[u/α] D[ψ4[u, v], u] - 
        2 I Sech[v/α] D[ψ4[u, v], v])) == 0};

bc = {ψ1[0, v] == Exp[-v^2], ψ4[0, v] == 0, ψ1[L, v] == Exp[-L^2], ψ4[L, v] == 0};
L = 5; α = 1; m = 1;
s = NDSolve[{eq, bc}, {ψ1[u, v], ψ4[u, v]}, {u, 0, L}, {v, 0, L}];

Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[ψ1[u, v]] /. s], {u, 0, L}, {v, 0, L}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Dear Alex Thank you very much. You helped a lot

Comment: @aber You're welcome!